# non-server controls and partial postbacks

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic, updatepanel, partial-postback

I'm inserting some non-server controls (plain html controls) dynamically into an update panel using jQuery.

If I do a full postback, I can get the values of those controls using Request.Form, however if I do a partial postback, I cannot.

Should I be able to get the values of html controls during a partial postback? Or only controls with runat="server"?

I am using non server controls as I'm playing around with facebox and file upload controls... it's not pretty :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update panel is not an efficient way of doing async.

As you're already using jQuery, add a web service (.asmx) to you project and hit that. See near figure 4 of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

Request.Form is built from the viewstate, which your controls won't have been added to.

Comment: Hmmm, can you explain how I would use a web service in this situation? I am using web services for other parts, but I'm rendering out a gridview also, so I'm wrapping it in an update panel for simplicity.

Comment: I don't believe that's entirely accurate... Request.Form reflects all of the variables received in the normal HTTP flow. Viewstate is actually one of the variables passed through this, as it is persisted through each postback.

Comment: When I've added controls to an update panel in a codebehind function, the values weren't present in Request.Form, hence my belief that the contents of viewstate were predefined...

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board. Any suggestions how I would use a dynamically added input file control to save a file asynchronously? I can't use server controls as the control will be dynamically added to a jquery facebox (does not play nice with server controls, i.e. duplicate id's)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the values of any form control or controls you want in a Partial Postback.  It is a trivial answer, but not intuitively obvious at first glance.  Maybe that's why ASP.net is dead.

Remember that the parameters of

```
__doPostback(string controlId,string param)
```

are strings, and the ASP.net methods

```
Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); // id
Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); // parameter
```

return strings.

Therefore the simple answer is to

1. Construct a javascript object with key values pairs of all your the form elements that you wish to send back in your partial.
2. Stringify that object, and pass it as the second parameter of your __doPostBack call.

On the server side you simply reverse this process to extract your object and all the form values you care about.

For example :

```
var strigifiedObject = JSON.stringify(myFormObject);
var id = "partialPostback";
__doPostBack(id, strigifiedObject);
```

... meanwhile on the server side

```
string id = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
string param = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT");

if (id == "partialPostback") {
    List<MyObj> formVals = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<MyObj>>>(param);
}
```